# Knockout observable array. Shared between multiple view models

Tags: javascript, knockout.js

Got a bit of a conundrum with a knockout observable array being shared across multiple view models.

Basically, I have a layout as follows

```
Transport
    ... textbox fields, etc

    Selected Passengers:
        <!-- ko foreach: allPassengers -->   
        <input type="checkbox" />
        <!-- /ko -->

    <button>Add Transport</button>

Holiday
    ... textbox fields, etc

    Selected Passengers:

        <!-- ko foreach: allPassengers -->   
        <input type="checkbox" />
        <!-- /ko -->

    <button>Add Holiday</button>
```

Now the selected passengers for each section is being generated from ONE observable array, idea being if a passenger is deleted/altered everything should fall into place automagically.

So something like this

```
function page() {
    // in actuality this passengers array is a computed observable obtained from the passengers section which is not shown here.
    this.allPassengers = ko.observableArray([
    {
        Id: 1,
        name = ko.observable('name'),
        checked = ko.observable(false)
    },
    {
     .
     .
    ]);
}

function transport() {
    // pageVM is a page object
    this.allPassengers = pageVM.allPassengers;

    this.transportItems = ko.observableArray();

    this.addTransport = function() {
        this.transportItems.push({
            .
            .
            selectedPassengers: [...]
            .
            .
        });
    };
}

function holiday() {
    // pageVM is a page object
    this.allPassengers = pageVM.allPassengers;

    this.holidayItems = ko.observableArray();

    this.addHoliday = function() {
        this.holidayItems.push({
            .
            .
            selectedPassengers: [...]
            .
            .
        });
    };
}
```

However, when add transport/holiday is clicked, I need a way to determine which checkboxs where checked so I can add the selected passengers.

I have tried to add a `checked = ko.observable(false)` property to the passenger item in `parent.allPassengers`, but the problem with this approach is if a checkbox is checked in the transport section it will also check it in the holiday section since it is using the same observable array.

Any ideas??

Edit:

[example fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/f9qFc/1/)

Comment: Can't there be two observables, `checkedTransport = ko.observable(false)` and `checkedHoliday = ko.observable(false)` in every passenger?

Comment: No I didn't want to adopt this approach, since we can have multiple holiday/transport sections. Besides I do not want the passenger section to have a dependency/knowledge on other sections...

Comment: Okay, makes sense. So `transportItems` should contain all the passenger objects for "Transport" and `holidayItems` all those for "Holiday"?

Comment: transportItems/holidayItems should contain objects which in turn should contain an array of selected passengers. I have added sample code that should execute when adding a transport/holiday to the items array.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The checked binding works with observable arrays too. So you can simply bind to `$parent.selectedPassengers` and specify the value attribute to be the passenger id, like this:

```
<input type="checkbox" data-bind="attr: { value: id },
                                  checked: $parent.selectedPassengers" />
```

In each view model you need to have a `selectedPassengers` observable array used for binding to the checkbox. And the add function should look like this:

```
function transport(pageVM) {
    ....
    this.selectedPassengers = ko.observableArray([]);    
    ....

    this.addTransport = function() {
        this.selectedItems.push({ 
            ....
            selectedPassengers: this.selectedPassengers()
        });
    };    
};
```

[Working Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/f9qFc/2/)

Comment: Nice answer David!  I had forgotten that checked worked with arrays.  You've got my upvote and I withdraw my answer.

Comment: Almost exactly the same, but using click bindings and manually updating the secondary array.  With the checked binding taking an array, it's much less work.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a `ko.computed` to return the selected passengers ([and here's a fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/DS2zS/)):

```
var ViewModel = function () {
    this.allPassengers = ko.observableArray([
        { name: 'John', selected: ko.observable(false) },
        { name: 'Jane', selected: ko.observable(false) },
        { name: 'Mark', selected: ko.observable(false) }
    ]);

    this.selectedPassengers = ko.computed(function () {
        return ko.utils.arrayFilter(this.allPassengers(), function (item) {
            return item.selected();
        });
    }, this);
};
```

Comment: This would suffer from the same problem as my fiddle above no? When used in multiple view models then checking a box in one section will check it in another...

Comment: Yeah, I missed the multiple view models thing and instead interpreted it as "one underlying array, multiple observable arrays." Oops.